# Spring Security formLogin()

Tags: spring, spring-security

Столкнулся с некоторой проблемой, есть форма авторизации

```
formLogin().loginPage("/enter/auth")
```

Я хочу перехватить POST запрос отсылаемый с формы

```
<form class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-form" action="/enter/auth" method="POST">
```

Но Interceptor видит все POST запросы, кроме этого, как можно решить проблему ?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете ввиду `HandlerInterceptor`, то он отрабатывает позже [цепочки фильтров](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) Spring Security, и соответственно, запрос не доходит до интерцептора. Чтобы перехватить этот запрос, вам нужно написать [свой фильтр](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters) и установить его до предоставляемого фреймворком `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` или наследоваться от данного фильтра и добавить интересующую вас реализацию.